# Java EE EAR shared location of read/write resources within clustered environment

Tags: java, deployment, jakarta-ee

Within a Java EE environment (happens to be WAS 6.1 but could be any application server) I need to place a XML file, which is a configuration file, so that I can read and write to it.

This needs to be available in a clustered environment so I am looking at using the class path to load the file.

I am thinking I can store this file in the EAR root, reference it in the manifest and then load and save it.

I have tried this approach by having my file in a JAR and making this available via the MANIFES and I can load the config file from the class path no problem using the following.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configFileName");
```

That loads the file that is in the JAR, which is fantastic.  But if I want to edit this file, programmatically, I cannot access the JAR files location (the EAR root) it returns me an interpreted path like this:

```
 /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/localhostNode01Cell/MyApp.ear/MyApp.war/TB_config.jar
```

That is not the correct location of the JAR the correct location is at MyApp.ear.

**So the question is:** how can I access and update (copy contents, create new, save, delete old) the JAR with my config file.
Or should I put the config file somewhere else?

What is the standard Java EE to make files that need read/write access available to WARs on a cluster?

Comment: There is any reason you have to use a file? Why not a db table?

Comment: The, well established, application uses a configuration file.  I am writing an admin app to administer the application.  Re-design of the application that uses the configuration file is not, alas, in scope.  This is something I have thought of.  Maybe even store in database and write to config file at engine initialisation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have built a solution for this.  It is more WebSphere based (our platform) but it is J2EE and I am suprised it was not mentioned.  Basically I have used JMX to synchronise the nodes.  The files are stored, and saved to, the deployment manager the nodes are then resynchronised using JMX calls and then the engines withing the applicaitons are restarted by calling servlets within the applications.

It works a dream

So @stacker, nodes are managed and the manager distributes files to the nodes.

Comment: Hi, do u mind to make a fiddle of this? I'm in the same scenario but your answer is not very clear to me. thanks!

Comment: @Mark hello sorry this was 6 years ago. I have not used websphere for about 5 years so I have no way to create a mock. Basically if you google for Websphere synchronize nodes with JMX you will get what you need to do. Then all you need to do is upload your files to the correct directory in the deployment manager and synchronize after that. For the correct directory I think a google for deployment manager distribution directory might give you something. Sorry I can be of no more help, good luck. To test you have the right dir copy something there then synch in admin console it goes to nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you've hit is not unique. A lot of Java EE programmers can struggle with providing a "configurable" property file to administrators of a cluster. And the solution that you've chosen, well, has its limitations.

The problem with embedding a config file inside a JAR, is absolute path or the physical path of the file, in case you need to update it. If your container will not explode your EAR and WAR files, then placing the config file alongside the code is a bad idea - the administrator will have to deploy a newer version of the EAR/WAR/JAR. That is unless, of course, you can configure the container to explode the artifacts - WebLogic Server does this, I'm not sure about WAS.

There are several ways to resolve this problem:

- Store the config file in a SAN that is accessible to all the nodes in the cluster via a 'canonical' path. That way, you could locate the file from any node in the cluster and update it. Remind yourself to restrict access to this directory. Although this sounds simple, it need not be - Java objects might have to be 'flushed' across nodes, once the configuration file has been updated. Moreover, you might have to cater to the scenario where property files can get edited outside the application.
- Use a database. Much simpler and almost hasslefree, except that the Java objects might have to be flushed again.
- Use a MBean. As good as a database, except that I haven't known a lot of people vouching for the MBean support in WAS. Also, I'm not really sure if object states can go haywire across a cluster, in this case.

Comment: Thinking about it what about WebSphere distributed objects? Also what about the network deployment manager architecture.  What about storing the file in a shared lib?  Are these not shared over the cluster when created at the ND level?  But then can I write to that shared lib?  I guess it depends then on file permissions and also may run into an issue with physical location.

Comment: Well, if you are aiming at little or no downtime, redeployment of artifacts it something that should be avoided, unless the application server supports versioning of managed objects like EJBs, i.e. it can continue processing requests using the older codebase until the new one has been completely deployed. I'm not really sure about WebSphere's capabilities in this area, but one thing I do know is that developers used to deploy a EJB JAR file with just the config file, as containers allow for in-flight redeployment of EJBs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to an ear file, you should place the XML file in the DB as a text lob (large object).

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for the reply.  Yes this has been considered and it maybe the solution.  But what about shared libs?  Would this be an option do you think.  Another reason that the DB solution has not already been implemented is that the configuration file should also be able to be hand edited outside of the admin app so DB, especially with a clob (character large object) would make manual editing not possible.

Comment: @Gurnard This can only be achived by shared files systems like NFS, or as Vineet described. How could one node (host) access antoher ones file system? Forget about writing to jar files. BTW if answers are helpful you should upvote and/or accept them (you can wait for a few days maybe a better answers is given).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as I am using WebSphere, it appears I can use the dynamic cache provided by the WebSphere deployment manager.  The last chapter in the link below dicusses the use of the Dynamic Cache providing a shared object in a cluster.  The configuration file is XML that is parsed as such by the engine (into a Document object) of the application and so is a Java object, thus it can be placed into the DistributedMap.

Looks like a clean solution.  Thanks all for reading and your replies.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0606_zhou/0606_zhou.html